# Update doesn't work in ADO.net Entity Data model

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I use *ADO.net Entity Data model* for work with database.

In my program, I want to update a record of user table, so I use the code below to do this.

In this function I send changed user info and then overwrite the information with the current user information.

After I run `objUser = _user;` and then call `objContext.SaveChanges();` to save the changes.

But when I do this, the changes are not persisted to the database. I use this code for another programs but in this case the code does not work!

```
public void Update(tbLiUser _user)
{
    LinkContext objContext = this.Context;

    tbLiUser objUser = objContext.tbLiUsers.First(u => u.tluId == _user.tluId);
    objContext.Attach(objUser);
    objUser = _user;

    objContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you already retrieve `objUser` from the `objContext`, there's really no point in attach that user to the context just after retrieving it. So I would drop this line here entirely:

```
objContext.Attach(objUser);
```

Also - you might just need to update the `objUser` on a per-property basis from the values in `_user` instead of just assigning the whole object.

To help you avoid lots of tedious code, you could use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to let you assign properties from one object type to the other. Or you could create a smart routine that would compare the two `objUser` and `_user` and update only those properties on `objUser` that are in fact different from the values in `_user` - shouldn't be too hard to create that method:

```
objUser.UpdateValuesFromOtherUser(_user);
objContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: objUser and _user are handles to objects. When you find objUser, you're finding an object, assigning its handle to objUser, and adding it to your context. When you then say objUser=_user, you're not updating the object, you're just pointing the variable to a different object. The context is still pointing to the old object. As marc_s says, you need to either copy properties one by one, or maybe there's some shortcut to copy them "in bulk", but the point is you have to update the existing object, not reassign it.